# Get value of selected values in power bi slicer

Tags: reporting-services, charts, powerbi, dax, dashboard

i have a slicer LOB as below:

[image]

i have a case where i need to validate if LOB slicer selected value is equal to Life or Medical (it could be both selected), than return true else false.

i tried using selectedvalue but didnt work if 2 values are selected

> LOB Selected = if(OR(SELECTEDVALUE('Production Report Treaty'[LOB])="Life",SELECTEDVALUE('Production Report Treaty'[LOB])="Medical"),TRUE,FALSE)

also tried using AllSelected but didnt know to completed it
do you know any idea how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SELECTEDVALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectedvalue-function) will give you a result only when there is a single value selected in the slicer. If you want to find if `Life` or `Medial` is selected, then you can look at the contents of the underlying table. It will be filtered to include only rows with values as specified in the slicer. So if `Life` is selected, then you will find a row with value `Life` in the table. The same with `Medical`. And also you may want to check is there is any value selected in the slicer or not by using [ISFILTERED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/isfiltered-function-dax) function.

So if you have a table like this:

[image]

And define a measure like this:

```
Life or Medical Selected = 

var LifeSelected = COUNTAX(FILTER(LOB_Table; LOB_Table[LOB] = "Life"); [LOB])
var MedicalSelected = COUNTAX(FILTER(LOB_Table; LOB_Table[LOB] = "Medical"); [LOB])

RETURN AND(ISFILTERED(LOB_Table[LOB]);OR(NOT(ISBLANK(LifeSelected)); NOT(ISBLANK(MedicalSelected))))
```

Then you can check is either one is selected

[image]

or not

[image]

Comment: thank you for your assistance , it is very helpful;
what if i only want to validate if Life, Medical, Or Life and Medical are selected without any other LOB, i.e. if Life and Marine are selected it should return False not True; True should be returned if only Life or Medical or (Life and Medical) without any other LOB selected.

Comment: Then get also counts where `LOB_Table[LOB] <> "Life"` and `LOB_Table[LOB] <> "Medical"` and adjust the logic in the return statement to look at these.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov If you have any time, Kindly check this and give me some suggestion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66525321/how-to-set-selected-value-from-slicer-to-api-in-powerbi

Answer (score 0):

i also was able to do it using the below mesure:

```
LOB Selected = 
if(
    (
        SELECTEDVALUE('Production Report Treaty'[LOB])="Life" ||
        SELECTEDVALUE('Production Report Treaty'[LOB])="Medical" ||
        CONCATENATEX(ALLSELECTED('Production Report Treaty'[LOB]),'Production Report Treaty'[LOB], ", ") = "Medical, Life")
    ,True
    ,False
)
```

regards,